# Is there a difference in drag force from air when going into a front tuck?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

The long jump is a track and field event in which athletes attempt to jump as far as possible from a take-off point into a sandpit.  Athletes and gymnasts will often independently discover the fact that it seems to be possible to travel slightly further in the long jump if one goes into a front tuck and performs a full rotation, instead of jumping forwards and following the usual ‘hitch-kick’ or ‘hang’ technique.

The Wikipedia page states that the flip technique allows for a slightly longer distance because power is not lost in counteracting forward momentum as in the usual hitch kick, and that when you somersault the drag force from the air is decreased.

I am unclear on whether reduction of drag is sufficient in the front tuck to allow for a longer horizontal distance.  Drag, acting like a frictional force, would work with gravity as the jumper goes up and again as they come down, but the forces have a vector nature.  Could one employ differential techniques to analyse the different impacts of drag on the orientation of the person in flight to compare the front tuck and the usual hitch kick techniques?

Comment: Drag acts opposite to the velocity, so there is also a horizontal component. In a very simple approximation, the cross sectional area in the direction of motion is the most important factor.

Comment: I am aware of the cross sectional area as an approximation, I am just not sure that is sufficient to make the argument that distance is longer.  Time in the air is a critical factor in how far the jumper moves during flight, so should one not also include kinematics in the argument?

Comment: You slow down in the air with more friction (everything else being equak). Therefore you move less far.

Comment: Video analysis would probably be helpful. My guess is that the summersault probably has less drag, and higher horizontal velocity, but the center of gravity isn’t as high, but if the center of gravity peak height is close, then maybe the reduced drag can help. Plus if rotating and able to pivot over the point of contact at the landing maybe that is another advantage.